# Spark SQL DataFrame - How to transform and create new one?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame created from reading a parquet file. I wanted to transform that DataFrame and create a new DataFrame.

**My Input File:**

```
Name      PhoneNumber
Shankar   2323232232
Ramesh    232j23j232
```

**Expected Output File:**

```
SHANKAR   2323232232
RAMESH    23223232
```

**Sample code to read input file:**

```
JavaSparkContext sc // An existing SparkContext.
SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
// Create the DataFrame
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().parquet("parquet file");
```

I want to apply `upperCase` on Name column and `filter any String or special characters` on PhoneNumber column(should accept only numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

df.select(
  upper(col("Name")).alias("Name"),
  regexp_replace(col("PhoneNumber"), "[^0-9]", "").alias("PhoneNumber"));
```